# User controls looks different when running the program (Visual studio 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls

i've created a custom user control (cicular progress bar) but when i run the project that circular bar looks different not like in design mode 
here's a picture to my problem
[image]

right side is the run mode

Comment: You should explain what the differences are, I cannot see any differences. Also please read about and provide a [mcve].

Comment: the difference is that in the design mode progress bar is perfectly circular but in runtime it looks more like an oval

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain the differences. Also, as I requested earlier, please add a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe you can try to set the form's property `AutoScaleMode` to `Dpi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe you can try to set the form's property `AutoScaleMode` to `Dpi` 
>   By Kyle Wang

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, specifically the code in the window that holds the control, I would guess that you have not constrained the control to have its height and width the same, so when it's in a container that gives it a non-square area, it will expand to fit.

You can either add code to the control to keep it square, or constrain the container so that the area given to the control is square. The former is more robust, as it avoids you forgetting when you use it again.